# How to grep for hex pattern w/ wildcards?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, hex

I'm trying to find the offset of a hex pattern in a file.  This works for one specific value:

```
$ grep -obUaP -m1 "\x00\x50\x53\x46\x01\x01\x00\x00\x34\x01\x00\x00" file.bin
3088:PSF4
```

However, this pattern includes a few bytes that will change, so I need to include wildcards in my grep.  I can't figure out how to do that.  Here's everything I've tried so far:

- `\x.., \x., ..,` and every similar form I can think of does not match
- `\x[0-9][0-9]` does not match
- `\x.*` does not match
- just `.*` (ie., `\x00.*\x01`) *does* match, but it's greedy and matches more than the pattern

Probably overlooking something silly, but I'm running into a wall here.

How do you specify a wildcard in hex, or at least when using grep with perl-regex to search for hex?

Comment: Using text tools to process binary data never ends well. Will the `grep` "Match any single character", "`.`" work? "`\x01.\x03`".

Comment: @waltinator That sounds like a reasonable solution. Does `.` match something like `\x00` (nul) too, or possibly some multi-byte character?

Comment: If you're using GNU `grep`, the `-U` option has no effect on non-MS-DOS/Windows systems. Also, using `-U` with `-a` seems odd.

Comment: @waltinator - you nailed it.  I could sworn I tried that, but apparently not.  Searching for this, matches the pattern in all my files:  "\x00\x50\x53\x46..\x00\x00..\x00\x00".  Thanks!  If you post as an answer I'll be happy to accept.  And while I don't disagree with your assessment about grep and binary files, it's the best tool I know of for this job and does the trick, though I'm certainly open to other suggestions.

Comment: @Kusalananda - agree with -U and -a being an odd combination.  I had picked this up from cobbling together answers about searching for offsets in binary files a while back and it worked, so didn't question it.  Just verified that it works without the -U, so going with that now.  Appreciate the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -P '\xAB'` doesn't look for a *hex character*. There is no such thing as a *hex character*. `\xAB` is PCRE *syntax* to match a character whose codepoint value expressed in hexadecimal is 0xAB (171 in decimal).

*codepoint* here would be the Unicode codepoint in locales that use UTF-8 and byte value in locales that use a single byte charset (GNU `grep -P` doesn't support multibyte charsets other than UTF-8).

So `\xAB` would match on the U+00AB character («) in a UTF-8 locale (where that character is encoded on 2 bytes: 0xc2 and 0xab) and the 0xAB byte in single-bytes locales (for instance, which represents the `Ћ` in a locale using the iso8859-5 charset).

If you want to match on byte value, you should make sure the locale uses a single-byte charset, the `C` locale is probably your best bet.

```
LC_ALL=C grep -P '\xAB'
```

matches on the 0xAB (171) byte, regardless of what character if any it represents in any charset.

To match on any single byte, again, you can use `.` (assuming the C locale or any local with single byte per character charset).

To match on a byte value within a range, as @Angle115 already said: `[\x01-\x45]` (here for byte values 1 to 0x45 / 69)

But bear in mind that `grep` matches on the *contents* of text *lines*¹, so it will never find the newline character which is the line delimiter and, regardless of the locale always has value 0x0A² (10 in decimal).

So `LC_ALL=C grep -P '\x23.\xab'` would match on a sequence of 3 bytes, the first one with value 0x23, the second with any value *except 0xA* and the third one with value 0xAB.

To be able to search for bytes with arbitrary values including 0xA, you'd need to treat the whole input as a whole, not one line or nul-delimited record at a time like `grep` does.

For that, you could use `pcregrep` with its `-M` (multiline) option along with the `(?s)` flag (for newline not to be treated specially by `.`) or use `perl` with its slurp-mode:

```
LC_ALL=C pcregrep --file-offsets -Ma '(?s)\x23.\xab' < file
```

(`pcregrep` doesn't have a `-b` option, `--file-offsets` which prints offset and length is probably the closest).

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print "$-[0]:$_" while /\x23.\xab/gs' < file
```

Or:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $-[0] if /\x23.\xab/s' < file
```

To only print the byte offset of the first match.

`perl` loads the whole file in memory, `pcregrep` doesn't but has internal limits that would likely prevent you from processing files where 0xA bytes are far apart.

---

<sup>¹ or NUL-delimited records with `--null`/`-z`</sup>

<sup>¹ on ASCII based systems. I don't even know if libpcre was ever ported to EBCDIC systems, I doubt many people will ever come across some of those these days.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response and clarifying some terminology.  In my script I am setting LC_ALL=C (have run into that issue previously), just didn't think to show that here.  Also very interested in what you noted about the 0x0A issue, which I also ran into after moving forward with @waltinator's answer.  Took a little while to connect the dots on that; eventually realized what was happening, but couldn't come up with a good way to match, so ended up having to refactor a bit to workaround that.  Very good to know about pcregrep -M in the future if needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can include a rang instead of using a wild card to match all ASCII characters, like so:

```
grep -Pe '\x00\x50\x53\x46[\x00-\x7F]\x01\x00\x00\x34\x01\x00\x00'
```